# TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'Home'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a very basic program of react with tsx, I am getting an error which I am not able to figure out why

```
import React from 'react';
// import {connect} from 'react-redux'

export class Home extends React.Component {    
    render(){
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>Working</div>
        )
    }
}


import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Home} from './Components/Home.component'
class App extends React.Component<any,any>{
render(){
    return(
        <Home value="abc" />
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App />, window.document.getElementById("app"))
```

git clone [this](https://github.com/waifo/employee.git) for code

Comment: Are you passing props down to this component? please further elaborate

Comment: This seems like a typescript type problem

Comment: please elaborate, show us the parent component that's passing the props

Comment: Looking into any react typescript examples, you should be extending `React.Component<any, any>`. I feel you are using typescript compiler but actually writing pure javascript.

Comment: React.Component<any, any>  have tried this it's not working

Comment: Please include the log of the error you are getting @MukeshKumar

Comment: This site can’t be reached codesandbox.io/s/moxzq0p7yp,

Comment: TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'Home' is the error

Comment: do u wnat to see the log file...? @fshock

Comment: The sandbox is working. Try it again https://codesandbox.io/s/moxzq0p7yp.

Comment: @fshock getting this error

This site can’t be reached

codesandbox.io unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Answer (score 66, accepted):

After pulling down your repo and inspecting it, I realised that you do not have [react typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react) for typescript.

> Typings is the simple way to manage and install TypeScript definitions

Adding this line

```
"@types/react": "^16.0.25" // or another version you prefer
```

to the `package.json` and running `npm i` or `yarn` if you are using yarn as a package manager, one more time, solved the issue.

Try it out and let me know if this solves it on your side :)

PS: TypeScript requires you to describe the shape of your objects and your data. If you look at the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47388544/6219957) I provided earlier, it was pretty much a long and complicated version of *You need to specify a type that describes your props and need to pass this to the component in question*

Comment: I tried this earlier it was not working, but now it's working. Thank you very much for your time and effort

Comment: I have defined this in devDependencies, i am trying to add in dependencies lets hope

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand

Comment: What seems to be the issue @Audiopolis

Comment: @Siya My situation was almost exactly the same as OP's, but adding react typings did nothing to fix the error. Defining the shape of props did fix the issue, however. Perhaps I have a stricter configuration or something. I'm new to TypeScript, so I'm sure I will understand better soon. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Awesome. Well, looking back at it now, typings alone is not enough, one still has to define the  state and props structure if they are going to be using it.

Comment: In Visual Studio, right-click npm in the project → Install New npm Packages...  and search for `@types/react' then Install Package.

Answer (score 22):

Typescript needs to know the shape of the `props` and `state` passed to a component. If you really want to stop Typescript from enforcing typings in your component (which, btw, defeats the whole purpose of using Typescript), then, the component that needs access to the `props` or `state` passed to it has to specify the type or shape so to speak, as `any`. That is, your component will look something like this

```
export class Home extends React.Component<any, any>
```

instead of

```
export class Home extends React.Component
```

*which btw, is an incorrect way of extending a class if that class expects `props` and/or `state`*.

Passing `any` type for `props` and `state` means that the component in question must accept any kind of shape (type) for both `props` and `state`.

Try this

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class Home extends React.Component<any, any> {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>Working</div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <Home value="abc" />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

and everything should work as expected because you got Typescript out of your way in terms of type-checking for you.

You can also view the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l53mnp1kj7)

If you actually wanted to enforce the shape (type) of the `props` and/or `state` you would then have to define these shapes with, usually, an `interface` or [inline type annotation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-system.html). Here is an example of the same code above that enforces the shape of the props using the former method:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface Props {
  value:string,
  name:string
}

export default class Home extends React.Component<Props>{
  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>Working. The props values are: {this.props.value} {this.props.name}</div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Home value="abc" name="def"/>
    )
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Now, here you could never be able to add any other `prop` to the `Home` component that is not defined in the `Props` interface.
For example doing something like:

```
<Home value="abc" name="DEF" somethin="else"/>
```

would not compile because `somethin` is not defined in the `interface` that is used by the `Home` component.

To enforce the shape of the `state` you'd have to do the same thing as for the `props`, i.e. define a contract (interface).
Also, note that you still need to access your `props` via `this` NOT `Props` as this is just a type definition of the structure not holder of the values themselves.

You can view the demo for this alternative [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/61mmovz6jz)

Comment: I don't think that is an issue, creating an interface for props and defining the prop types is just for validation, i have created may components without interface props and it used to work fine

Comment: Well, I have tested this and it does not work without having the shape of the  props defined somewhere. The only time it works is when I have ordered the component to accept any kind of props.

Comment: Which version of Typescript are you getting the above error in? Is it the same version you wrote the components that did not require a structure of the props or state?

Comment: My dependencies     
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "react": "^16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "ts-loader": "^3.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^3.8.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.4"

Comment: Okay, thanks. Have you tried the suggested approaches, above? Also, you do not need to create an interface for props. That is the second part of the answer and I mentioned that it would the approach you'd take if and only if you wanted to enforce some kind of structure for your props and/or state

Comment: i have added link to repo you can clone and try