# React with TypeScript: Type '{}' is not assignable to type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component in React that shows a navigation based on a prop. I cannot figure out why I am getting this error when I'm trying to run the application:

```
(19,8): Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TableSystems> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }...'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ todos: any; showNav: boolean; }>'.
    Property 'todos' is missing in type '{}'.
```

My component look like this:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import Navigation from '../components/Navigation'
import TableSystems from '../components/TableSystems'

class SystemTable extends React.PureComponent<{showNav: boolean }> {
  render(){
  return (

    <div >
    <div >
    <div className="navigationContainer">
    <Navigation {...this.props.showNav} className="sideMenu"/>
      <TableSystems/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>)
  }
}


export default SystemTable
```

I can't find what's the problem here.

The  component looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import history from '../history';


class Navigation extends React.Component<any>  {

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.toVersions = this.toVersions.bind(this);
  }

  toVersions(){
    history.push('/versions');
  }

  render() {
    var style = this.props.visible ? "toggled" : "";
    console.log(style);
    return (
      <div className={style} id="wrapper">


        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
          <ul className="sidebar-nav">
            <li className="sidebar-brand">
              <a href="#">
                Menu
              </a>
            </li>
            <li >
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">List1</a>
            </li>
            <li >
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">List2</a>
            </li>
            <li >
              <a className="nav-link" href="" onClick={this.toVersions}>List3</a>
            </li>
            <li >
              <a className="nav-link" href="#">List4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Navigation
```

Comment: I think you mean to spread `props` not `showNav`, as in not `{...this.props.showNav}` not `{...this.props}`

Comment: Titian - that is done intentioanlly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240449/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattribu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the solution was to add {...this.props} to  component like so:

```
<TableSystems {...this.props}/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to either make the property `todos` optional by defining it as `todos?: any` or you will have to pass in a value to it: `{ todos: null, showNav: boolean }`.

Comment: I think Titan (on the original post) has correctly assessed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

While I can only guess the element throwing the error (no clue where line 19 is), the error is quite self explanatory:

```
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<{ todos: any; showNav: boolean; }>'. Property 'todos' is missing in type '{}'.
```

The component expects a `todo` property and a `showNav` property, you are providing none of these. Try specifying the props explicitly:

```
<YourElement todos={ this.props.whatever } showNav={true}> ... </YourElement>
```

Another solution is to use the spread operator to use an objects properties for the element's props:

```
const someVar = { todos: "your type for todos here", showNav: true };

<YourElement { ...someVar } \>
```

Ensure you also type your element's props:

```
interface Props {
    prop: string;
}

const SampleElement: React.SFC<Props> = (props) =>
    <div>{props.prop}</div>

class AnotherElement extends React.Component<Props> { ... }
```