# How to pass data in reactjs using typescript

Tags: reactjs, components, pass-data, tsx

How to pass object to child component in reactjs using tsx. I'm geting this error when I tried this way. Where I can declare the type? 
`Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ShipmentCard>`

**Cards.tsx**

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.card.map((card: any) => (
          <ShipmentCard key={card.id} value={card}/>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The full error message is:

> Type '{ key: any; data: any; }' is not assignable to type
>   'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
>   Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'. Property 'data'
>   does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{
>   children?: ReactNode; }>'

Comment: full error message `Type '{ key: any; data: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ShipmentCard> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ShipmentCard> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using typescript then you have to declare all props in ShipmentCard.tsx

```
interface ShipmentCardProps {
    key: string;
    value: {}
}

interface ShipmentCardState {}

class ShipmentCard extends React.Component<ShipmentCardProps, ShipmentCardState> {
}
export default ShipmentCard
```

Comment: @SKL Its great that i am able to help

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf). have you 'card' in your state? It seems like no. You need to get props from parent component. You need to try pass data using props. So read the link. And try to use redux.

Comment: yes i did. When console.log `this.props` in `render()` it is showing empty object. tsx checking type thats why throwing this error

Comment: The object is empty twice? during mounting, it could be empty. What happened after update (second render)

Comment: If u pass an obejct in `value` attribute its throwing an error but value still showing console log. Error `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<ShipmentCard> & Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'` This issue will be fixed if we fix type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240449/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattribu

I have found this answer. It says: "You must give propTypes and stateType when you use typescript."