# How to pass an object to a custom child component in ReactJS using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-component

### Objective

I want to fetch data in App's root component via `useEffect()` (and set them to state) and then pass state to my custom component. I can do it with JS but the same steps don't work with Typescript.

My error message is the following:

```
Type '{ obj: Person; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes 
& Person & { children?: ReactNode; }'. Property 'obj' does not exist 
on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Person & { children?: ReactNode; }'.TS2322
```

To me, it looks like I have an object with Person type I can't assign to another type of Person...

### App.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Profile from '../Profile';

export interface Person {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  dob: string;
  address: string;
  number: string;
  userName: string;
  pssw: string;
};

const initPerson: Person = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  dob: "",
  address: "",
  number: "",
  userName: "",
  pssw: ""
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [ profile, setProfile ] = useState<Person>(initPerson)

  useEffect(() => {
    // logic for fetching data and setting the state
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <h1>Random user generator</h1>
      <div id="content">
        <Profile obj={profile} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Person.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Person } from './app/App'

const Profile: React.FC<Person> = (props) => {
    return (
        <div id="Card">
            {/* photo */}
            <div id="photo"><img src="" alt="profile" /></div>
            {/* name */}
            <div id="name"></div>
            {/* email */}
            <div id="email"></div>
            {/* dob */}
            <div id="dob"></div>
            {/* adress */}
            <div id="address"></div>
            {/* number */}
            <div id="number"></div>
            {/* pssw */}
            <div id="password"></div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

I could not find any relevant YT video nor previous post here... Based on these questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348905/how-to-pass-data-in-reactjs-using-typescript) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/dm6ljl/why_is_typescript_not_stupid/)) I think I need to declare the interface of my component?

If so:

- Where?
- Why do I need to declare the interface of my component if I have already defined interface for Person that I am passing to my component?
- How should the declaration look like?
- What is the error telling me?
- How should I pass data to the child component correctly? (and also from child to parent)
- Also is there something else I should know?

Any help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that this

```
const Profile: React.FC<Person>
```

should be this

```
const Profile: React.FC<{ obj: Person }>
```

That is, `props` isn't of type `Person`, you have a `obj` prop in `Profile` which is of type `Person`.

The type parameter `T` in `React.FC<T>` needs to be the shape of all your custom props, on top of the built in React ones (i.e. `children`) - so basically an object with fields.

For instance if you had another prop `foo` which should be a number, it would be `React.FC<{ obj: Person, foo: number }>`, etc.

Comment: Hi @davciwill and thanks for your answer. It helped. Now I understand how to create an interface for `props` I am passing to my child component. 

For future readers, I would like to also point out on @Luis Paulo Pinto answer where he makes an interface for `props`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a prop shape that's actually

```
export interface Person {
  obj: {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    dob: string;
    address: string;
    number: string;
    userName: string;
    pssw: string;
  }
};
```

but you declared

```
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  dob: string;
  address: string;
  number: string;
  userName: string;
  pssw: string;
};
```

Since I see you like to learn and try things out, I'll let you figure out where the adjustment can be done! If not, let me know and I'll add more details.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I understand what you tried to tell me (and also read other answers). I also now understand that I am passing `obj: Person`. 
OK, I think I get it now. In JS I am used to destructuring props and therefore use `{obj}` instead of `props.obj`. That's the same in typescript I just need to correctly define all props I am passing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```js
// Here you create an interface for Profile component that receives an "obj" prop of Person type.
interface ProfileProps {
  obj: Person;
}

const Profile: React.FC<ProfileProps> = (props) => {
   console.log(props.obj);
   return (
   ....
```

And now you will be good, because when you set Profile tag in App Component you are passing the obj prop:

```
<Profile obj={profile} />
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. It also definitely help. My questions if the name `ProfileProps` (or rather componentName + Props) is mandatory naming or if I can pick some other random name for `ProfileProps`. 
Is it convention or has it some other meaning/purpose?

Comment: Hi Lukas, its just a convention that i use, for me it let the code more readable - When i see something like this `Profile: React.FC<ProfileProps>` i know this Component has some custom props. But basically you can name it any way you want and find a convention that makes you more comfortable.