# TypescRipt Error Could not pass props to component ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I just started typescript and I'm having issue which I cant solve.
I'm trying to pass props from one functional component to another.
But Whenever I'm trying to do it I'm getting this error.

```
<PostOnPage info={items.id} />   


 Type '{ info: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'info' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.  TS2322
```

Is there any way to solve this?

I thought It was because of props type in my second component and I tried to change it like this.

```
const PostOnPage: React.FC = (props: any) => {
```

But it did not work.
Help me please

Comment: Add an `any` type parameter to `React.FC`. That is, `React.FC<any>`. Your error is because the type parameter is `{}` by default, which means your component doesn't allow any props.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240449/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattribu

Comment: Did you tried - passing props like this way - <PostOnPage ...postOnPageProps />  
where you have to ensure that postOnPageProps Props keys and types matches.