# Variable does not exist on type error on code copied from MUIv5 example

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

### ***The Goal***

I'm trying to create a drawer sidebar in MUI5 that opens and closes when the user presses a button. So I am looking at the [docs for the Drawer](https://mui.com/components/drawers/#persistent-drawer), and [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rt68rw?file=/demo.js:0-6458).

---

### ***The Problem***

I have copied the code from [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/rt68rw?file=/demo.js:0-6458) and pasted it directly into my project, but I get the following error:

```
22 | 
23 | const Main = styled('main', { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
24 |   ({ theme, open }) => ({
   |             ^
25 |     flexGrow: 1,
26 |     padding: theme.spacing(3),
```

I had a few other errors similar to this that I was able to solve using this SO Question: [Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240449/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattribu)

However, it doesn't seem to work for defining `open`.

---

### ***Main question***

***How do I define `open` so that I can have a drawer?***

---

### ***Bonus Question***

***Why is my MUI different than CodeSandbox's MUI?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You copied the JavaScript version of the example rather than the TypeScript version. On the examples in the documentation, you can find a symbol (`<>`) for showing the full source (rather than just a snippet). Expanding the full source also shows a JS/TS (JavaScript/TypeScript) toggle on the left. Selecting "TS" will give you the TypeScript version of the code and your selection is remembered for other examples and when you return to the site later. Clicking the sandbox icon will take you to the corresponding version of the code. Here is the TypeScript sandbox for the Persistent Drawer example: https://codesandbox.io/s/9ohdw8?file=/demo.tsx.

[image: Persistent drawer docs]