# How to fix the Type ‘{handleIndex: ()=> void}’ is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes' with TypeScript and React?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript so I don't know why this error happens and how to fix it...
This is my code.

```js
export default function SignupPage() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState<number>(0);

  const handleIndex = () => {
    setIndex(index + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <BasicInfo handleIndex={handleIndex} /> // error
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to pass `handleIndex` function as a prop of `BasicInfo` component and I get this error:

```
Type ‘{handleIndex: ()=> void}’ is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

What can I do about it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240449/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattribu

Comment: Please can u share your `BasicInfo` component code?

Comment: @ToniBardinaComas This is my BasicInfo component code!!

export default function BasicInfo() {
  return (
    <div>
        <TextBox>
          <Text
            bold //
            color="#D55B42"
          >
            *
          </Text>
          <Text bold>성별</Text>
        </TextBox>
    </div>
  );
}

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your `BasicInfo` component I can see that it is not expecting any prop. You should add handleInfo to props:

```
function BasicInfo({handleIndex}) {...}
```

Comment: Oh I'm very new to Typescript so I didn't know that! Thank you so much!!