# Type '{ category: Category; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'. Property 'category' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, fetch-api

I'm a beginner to TypeScript and NextJS and i've run into a problem where I can't pass data to my form due to IntrinsicAttributes Error. This is the error I'm getting.

```
Type '{ category: Category; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'category' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

I'm trying to send the category to the Edit Category Form but the above error is in the category attribute of EditCategoryForm.

```
import EditCategoryForm from "@/app/ui/base/categories/edit-category-form";
import Breadcrumbs from "@/app/ui/breadcrumbs";
import { getCategoryById } from "@/app/lib/data/base/categories-data";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

export default async function EditCategoryPage({
  params,
}: {
  params: { id: number };
}) {
  const id = params.id;
  const category = await getCategoryById(id);
  console.log("Category in the Edit Category Page - ", category);

  if (!category) {
    notFound();
  }
  return (
    <main>
      <Breadcrumbs
        breadcrumbs={[
          { label: "Base", href: "/dashboard/base" },
          { label: "Categories", href: "/dashboard/base/categories" },
          {
            label: "Edit Category",
            href: `/dashboard/base/categories/${id}/edit`,
            active: true,
          },
        ]}
      />
      <EditCategoryForm category={category} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

This is my edit category form.

```
"use client";

import { Category } from "@/app/lib/definitions";
import { CurrencyDollarIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import Link from "next/link";
import { Button } from "@/app/ui/button";
import { updateCategory } from "@/app/lib/actions/base/categories-actions";

export default function EditCategoryForm({ category }: { category: Category }) {
  const updateCategoryWithId = updateCategory.bind(null, String(category.id));
  console.log("Category in the Edit Category Form - ", category);

  return (
    <form action={updateCategoryWithId}>
      <div className="rounded-md bg-gray-50 p-4 md:p-6">
        {/* Category Name*/}
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label htmlFor="name" className="mb-2 block text-sm font-medium">
            Category Name
          </label>
          <div className="relative mt-2 rounded-md">
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                id="name"
                name="name"
                type="string"
                placeholder="Enter Category Name"
                className="peer block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-2 pl-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
                defaultValue={category.name}
                aria-describedby="cat-name-error"
              />
              <CurrencyDollarIcon className="pointer-events-none absolute left-3 top-1/2 h-[18px] w-[18px] -translate-y-1/2 text-gray-500 peer-focus:text-gray-900" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="mt-6 flex justify-end gap-4">
        <Link
          href="/dashboard/base/categories"
          className="flex h-10 items-center rounded-lg bg-gray-100 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-gray-600 transition-colors hover:bg-gray-200">
          Cancel
        </Link>
        <Button type="submit">Edit Category</Button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

This is my Category type and Subcategory.

```
export type Category = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  subcategories: Subcategory[];
};

export type Subcategory = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  category: Category;
};
```

This is how I'm fetching the data. The data is fetched properly.

```
export async function getCategoryById(id: number) {
  noStore();
  try {
    const response = await fetch(API_URL_CATEGORIES + "/" + String(id) + "/");
    const body: Category = await response.json();
    return body;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Database Error:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch category.");
  }
}
```

I'm unable to see the form due to this error. Am I declaring the props wrong? What is the Intrinsic Attributes error? I've passed everything properly though.

Comment: If i am not wrong, you are returning a promise in JSX Element?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling getCategoryById(id) in my EditCategoryPage. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: I do not know how are you calling a JSX Component which is returning a Promise. Check this: https://prnt.sc/H8hGwOeobel9

Comment: I'm trying to fetch the particular category with the ID using fetch API in getCategoryById(id) mentioned above. How else can I can fetch the particular ID and send it to my form?

Comment: You are passing `Promise<Category>` to `EditCategoryForm` , not the Category. Either resolve the promise, and then send it to your Form OR Resolve it inside your Form component.

Comment: I followed the code that you put below to resolve it inside the form. However, I'm getting the same error. How do I resolve it and then send to the form?

Comment: Remove async/await from this line: ```const category = getCategoryById(id);``` and from its function aswell and then try the same?

Comment: I need the async/await in my fetch API function else it throws an error. If i remove the async in the `const category = getCategoryById(id);` the error still remains. I've gone through all the stackoverflow and reddit posts and tried all the methods but this error is very frustrating. Is it possible to disable TypeScript for just this one thing?

Comment: You shouldn't be disabling TS for particular files, its possible but not the best solution. I didn't get any errors with my solution. Please try to accommodate your requirements with my solution. This might be your best bet!

Answer (score 0):

1. Within EditCategoryForm, ensure you're correctly accessing properties of the category object.
   For ex: `<input type="text" value={category.name} />`
2. If using {...category} solves your specific issue, it might be because the category object contains properties that are expected as separate props in your EditCategoryForm component. But it might not always be the best solution.

Ref:
[Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48240449/type-is-not-assignable-to-type-intrinsicattributes-intrinsicclassattribu)

I tried the below sample code. it works fine for me

Edit Page

```
import { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Category, getCategoryById } from '../types';
import EditCategoryForm from '@/components/EditCategoryForm';
export const metadata: Metadata = {
    title: 'test', 
}
export default async function Edit() {
    const id = 1;
    const category: Category| undefined = await getCategoryById(id);
    console.log("Category in the Edit Category Page - ", category);
    return (
        <>
            <main>
                {
                    category ? <>    <EditCategoryForm category={category} /></> : <></>
                }
            </main>
            );
        </>
    )
}
```

types.ts

```
export interface Category {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  subcategories: Subcategory[];
}

interface Subcategory {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  // Other properties of Subcategory
}
  export const getCategoryById = async (id: number)  => {
    // Simulate an asynchronous fetch operation
    return  categoriesList.find((cat) => cat.id === Number(id));
  };
  
  const categoriesList : Category[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Category 1', subcategories: [] },
    { id: 2, name: 'Category 2', subcategories: [] },
    { id: 3, name: 'Category 3', subcategories: [] },
  ];
```

Edit form

```
export default function EditCategoryForm({ category }: { category: Category }) {
  console.log("Category in the Edit Category Form - ", category.name);

  return ( .... 
  );
}
```

Comment: 1. Yes, I'm accessing everything correctly. 
2. When I do that using <EditCategoryForm {...category} />, I get a new error.

Type '{ id: number; name: string; subcategories: Subcategory[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

Comment: (2) error: then explicitly pass the  values.  i resolved the same issue  when i faced.

Comment: You mean like this right - <EditCategoryForm id={category.id} name={category.name} />. It still raises the same error.

Comment: did you changed  in EditCategoryForm as  EditCategoryForm({ id, name, subcategories }: Category) ?

Comment: Yup, I changed the EditCategoryForm. This is the error I get which is same as before - Type '{ id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.

Comment: Can you paste the entire code fior the page EditCategoryPage, EditCategoryForm  , it will help us to find the issue

Comment: Pasted the entire code.

Comment: ok , can you define the type in const category: Category = await getCategoryById(id);

Comment: Yes I did but it's the same error.

Comment: I am not sure, try to change  Category type to an interface... 
 export interface Category {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  subcategories: Subcategory[];
}

Comment: Yeah I tried all that before making the post here

Comment: @asasin check my sample code

Comment: I checked it but its the same error thats arising. I just edited the code above. Could it be because both my Category and Subcategory interface are referencing each other? I just noticed it now and it seems to be the only logical explanation. Ill try to separate them and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but i am not sure if it will fit your requirements of your project, but i still want to give it a chance.

I have made following changes to your code:

EditCategoryPage.tsx:

```
    async function getCategoryById(id: string) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('/category.json');
            const body: Category = await response.json();
            return body;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Database Error:", error);
            throw new Error("Failed to fetch category.");
        }
    }

    export default function EditCategoryPage(params: { id: string }) {
        const id = params.id;
        const category = getCategoryById(id);
    
        return (
            <main>
                <EditCategoryForm category={category}/>
            </main>
        );
    }
```

App.tsx:

```
    function App() {
        return (
            <>
               <EditCategoryPage id={"2"} />
            </>
        );
    }
```

EditCategoryForm.tsx:

```
    export default function EditCategoryForm( props : { category: Promise<Category> }) {
        props.category.then(value => {console.log(value)})
        return (
            <>
    
            </>
        )
    }
```

This is my placeholder JSON File:

```json
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "NAME",
      "subcategories": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "something": "something.."
        }
      ]
    }
```

Result/Console:

[image: Result]

*Let me know if you have any trouble/issues with this solution.*

Comment: I'm assuming the change is adding (props : { category: Promise<Category> ) to the EditCategoryForm instead? I'm still getting the same error. I'll upload the whole code now if that helps.

Comment: Yes please, you can use sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

This was a case of importing the wrong file. Instead of importing EditCategoryForm from "@/app/ui/base/categories/edit-categories-form", I imported from "@/app/ui/base/categories/edit-category-form". Found the answer on a reddit page where another user had the same issue due to importing the wrong file.