# Understanding TS2345: "Argument of type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

We're trying to wrap a Typescript React component in [`react-onclickoutside`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside) - but when we do so, we get the error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentConstructor<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps & HandleClickOutside<any>> | ClickOutComponentClass<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps>'.
  Type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps & HandleClickOutside<any>, any>'.
    Construct signature return types 'MyComponent' and 'Component<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps & HandleClickOutside<any>, any, any>' are incompatible.
      The types of 'props' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps & HandleClickOutside<any>> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
          Type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps & HandleClickOutside<any>>': disableOnClickOutside, enableOnClickOutside, handleClickOutside
```

**Our failing code is like this:**

```js
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props, State> {
  //  ...
}

export const WithOnClickOutside = onClickOutside(MyComponent);
```

We have `@types/react-onclickoutside` installed; I'm not sure what else I need to do to get this working.

---

I'm a Typescript noob, so please let me know if there's additional context needed that I've failed to provide.

Answer (score 1):

The property definitions are missing from your class, try updating the props type of your component to include the intersection of the types it asks for.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps & HandleClickOutside<any>, State> {
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately it makes no difference whether we define all or none of those.

Comment: Can you change `React.PureComponent<Props, State>` to include the intersection of the other two types? It should look like this `React.PureComponent<Props & InjectedOnClickOutProps & HandleClickOutside<any>, State>`

Comment: Thanks for that idea! Unfortunately that gives me `TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'` - any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47387628/ts2339-property-props-does-not-exist-on-type-home . To see the effect of installing the package, you may need to restart your IDE.